# SQL Server : different execution plan and performance for similar queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have 2 queries on the same table and I have expected similar performance, still I get a huge difference - 30 seconds versus ~ 1 second.

Query 1: count users for current month

```
SELECT datepart(year,getdate()) as TheYear, 
       DATEPART(month, GETDATE()) AS TheMonth, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT Username) AS TheUsers
FROM dbo.[AP-Data] 
WHERE datepart(year,RequestDate) =  datepart(year,getdate()) 
  AND datepart(month,RequestDate) = datepart(month,getdate())
```

Query 2: count users for current week

```
SELECT datepart(year,getdate()) as TheYear, 
       DATEPART(week, GETDATE()) AS TheWeek, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT Username) AS TheUsers
FROM dbo.[AP-Data] 
WHERE datepart(year,RequestDate) =  datepart(year,getdate()) 
  AND datepart(week,RequestDate) = datepart(week,getdate())
```

The table has ~ 3.5 million records and it is indexed by `RequestDate`. The count for the month is doing a full table scan, so it takes 30 seconds, the one for the week is doing RID Lookup in ~ 1 second - this information is coming from the execution plans.

Any idea why the difference?

Comment: Do some research on if something is SARG-able. If you use a function on a column in your join or where clause, you usually cannot leverage an index on it.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `DATEPART(something,RequestDate)` on the `WHERE` at all. Try to rewrite them to use something like:`WHERE RequestDate >= CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),GETDATE(),112) + '01'` or similar

Comment: Thank you, I tried this and I got also strange results: 

'SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Shortname) AS TheUsers FROM dbo.[AP-Data] WHERE RequestDate > '2017-03-01'
runs in a second. But 
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Shortname) AS TheUsers FROM dbo.[AP-Data] WHERE RequestDate > CONCAT(datepart(year,getdate()),'-0',datepart(month,getdate()),'-01') 
runs in 30 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

How about trying these queries?

```
SELECT year(getdate()) as TheYear, month(GETDATE()) AS TheMonth,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Username) AS TheUsers
FROM dbo.[AP-Data]
WHERE RequestDate >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0);
```

and:

```
SELECT year(getdate()) as TheYear, month(GETDATE()) AS TheMonth,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Username) AS TheUsers
FROM dbo.[AP-Data]
WHERE RequestDate >= dateadd(week, datediff(week, 0, getdate()), 0);
```

Using functions on columns usually prevents the compiler from using an index.  The above assumes that you don't have future request dates.

Comment: They both work in 1 second. It's just the WEEK one was working fine in my initial query and I am still interested to understand where is the difference coming from.

Comment: Also trying to get the COUNT for the previous month, it does not work (fast):

`SELECT year(getdate()) as TheYear, month(GETDATE()) AS TheMonth,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Username) AS TheUsers
FROM dbo.[AP-Data]
WHERE RequestDate >= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate())-1, 0) AND RequestDate < dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, getdate()), 0);`